# If substring in df['column']: add value to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring, contains

I have two columns in a dataframe as such:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| apple x2 | 1 |
| banana | 0 |
| apple x3 | 1 |

If apple is present, the count is already set to 1. I need to extract is 'x' is present and then add the value after 'x' to the count column (it will be the value minus 1 to get the right amount).

Is there a way to do this vectorized without a loop?

I tried this loop:

```
for fruit in df['Name']:
    if fruit.str.contains('x', case = False, na = False):
        add = fruit[:-1]
        df['Count'] = df['Count'] + add - 1
```

I get this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I think I am way off here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can use `to_numeric()` method and `fillna()` method and `astype()` method:

```
df['Count']=df['Count']+pd.to_numeric(df['Name'].str[-1],errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Now If You print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    Name        Count
0   apple x2    3
1   banana      0
2   apple x3    4
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then pls try considering accepting this answer so as to indicate others that the issue is solved......Thank you **:)**